# How do I apply ormap to a single variable? - Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Working on this project for hours now and I can't figure it out.

I have a list of numbers and I need it to produce true if any of those numbers matches a separate number without using recursion.

```
(compare-numbers (list 1 2 3) 2) => true
```

What I know I have to do is use ormap on a local function, but I can't figure out how to make the function.

What I wrote is

```
(define (comp? num)
  (equal? num num-lst)) ;Where num-lst is the list of accepted numbers
```

But I know I can't use this as ormap needs two lists to work.

Can anyone throw me a hint at solving this?
Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._ormap%29%29

Comment: Why do you think `ormap` needs two lists? The example in the Racket manual only has one.

Answer (score 0):

`ormap` doesn't need two lists. It just needs a procedure that compares a list element to the given number, which you can create with `lambda`.

```
(define (compare-numbers lst num)
  (ormap (lambda (n) (equal? n num)) 
         lst))
```